# Aurelia Skeleton export unbundled

Tags: aurelia

Is there a way to export the project unbundled?  I have a javascript error that happens in the prod environment but not in Dev and it would be nice to be able to debug human readable javascript/typescript instead of the uglified bundled code.

I'm using the jspm/gulp/typescript skeleton.

Comment: I'm guessing you're using one of the JSPM based skeletons?

Comment: Yes.  Sorry, forgot to mention that. I'll add it to the question.

Comment: I'm playing with this. It might help to add the SystemJS and JSPM tags to the question. Under the covers, all the aurelia bundler does is call the System Builder API. I'm getting some strange results though when I try to enable source maps

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a temporary answer, that I'm not exactly happy with... Mainly because things aren't working how they *should*.

If you add `"sourceMaps": 'inline'` to the `options` listed in `build/bundles.js` AND ALSO copy the `src` folder over to the `export` folder, then you should get *some* sourcemap support. It doesn't seem to be working completely though for me, but it might be good enough to work with.

The fact that I tell the bundler to put the sourcemaps inline (and when I base64 decode the sourcemap it seems it is actually inline) but then I still have to add the contents of `src` directory to make it work doesn't seem right.

It'll look something like this:

[image]

I'm not sure if the issue is on the Aurelia side or the System Builder side though.

Comment: awesome, I'll give that a try.  Until this suggestion I was essentially copying the dist folder instead of the export folder and copying the entire jspm directory and copying the src folder and the config.js.  So if I can whittle that down to just the src folder, I'll be happy :-)